# I'm trying to implement a Search Filter in React, but it doesn't work, could you help me out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to build a search filter fetching an API, the console doesn't give me any error, but the filter search bar doesn't work, could someone help me out? Thank you!

So, I think everything should be fine, because in the chrome console, I don't receive any errors, but the SearchBox.js, doesn't seem to work

This is the code:

SearchBox.js:

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      suggestions: [],
      text: '',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.scryfall.com/catalog/card-names')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(cards => this.setState({ suggestions: cards.data}))
  }

  onTextChanged = (event) => {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const value = event.target.value;
    let suggestions = [];
    if (value.length > 0) {
      const regex = new RegExp(`^${value}`, '');
      suggestions = Object.keys(items).sort().filter(word => regex.test(word))
  }
  this.setState(() => ({ suggestions, text: value }))
}

suggestionSelected (value) {
  this.setState({
    text: value,
    suggestions: []
  });
}


renderSuggestions () {
  const { suggestions } = this.state;
  if (suggestions.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <ul>
      {suggestions.map((item, index) => <li key={index} onClick={() => this.suggestionSelected(item)}>{item}</li>)}
    </ul>
  )
}

  render () {
    const { text } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input value={text}
          onChange={this.onTextChanged} type="text" />
          {this.renderSuggestions()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default SearchBox;
```

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox';
class App extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <SearchBox items/>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: In your App.js you pass items as a boolean prop not as an object. Define items object and pass it like this: <SearchBox items={items} />

Comment: Hi @gergana, thank you! Since I'm really newbie on it, how do I define items as an object? Thank you for your help and patient!

Comment: Depends on what the structure you want to be of your object. You can explain what you want your object to be so I can give you suggestions. In your onTextChanged function I think you should filter suggestions from state not items.

Comment: For object do you mean a component? Filtering the state of suggestions?

Comment: You try to map items like an object right here:  Object.keys(items), but you pass boolean. What is the purpose of the input text? When the user searches for a text it should search from the suggestions right?

Comment: If I don't Object.keys(items), I can't call the sort method on items, because it will be undefined. Yes, the suggestions array, should populate

Comment: Yes, but in your case isn't items boolean variable ??

Comment: Sort suggestions instead of items in your onTextChanged function. Take a look at this search example: https://codepen.io/iamtimsmith/pen/zJPzwN

Comment: I define items, with the purpose to filter them, to get the suggestions, based on what the user type on the input text. It works with some hard coded data stored in an array, where i export them, call them in the App.js and passing <SearchBox items={*filename with hard coded data*}. But I'm not sure by fetching the data from an API

Comment: But the list of the data, still appear in the browser, even if I defined "null" in the renderSuggestions, my goal was to hide the data, and when the user type something on the input, should give the suggestions

Comment: Take a look at this simple example https://dev.to/sage911/how-to-write-a-search-component-with-suggestions-in-react-d20

Comment: @gergana, I managed to fix the problem wby changing the const { items } with: const items = this.state.suggestions, and then I deleted the Object.keys and just applied .filter on items. Now I need to figure out why the data are not hiding. Thank you for the patience and the effort to help me out! I appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Yes, I thought you should filter the suggestions. You can save in state the filtered suggestion and display only that one in render method.

Comment: Please update your code and I can help you with the last part :)

Comment: Thank you! I'm sending the a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-williamson-5vfry?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @gergana Solved it! Thank you again for your precious help!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the functions bindings:

```
class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      suggestions: [],
      text: '',
    }

    // == Binding ==
    this.suggestionSelected = this.suggestionSelected.bind(this);
    this.renderSuggestions = this.renderSuggestions.bind(this);
    this.onTextChanged = this.onTextChanged.bind(this);
    // == ======= ==

  }

// [...]

}
```

Comment: Check this for more info: https://medium.com/shoutem/react-to-bind-or-not-to-bind-7bf58327e22a

Comment: Also, since last year you can use state in functional components, which are more simple and easy to handle. https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/react-hooks-explained-functional-components-with-state-122cc7faf770

Comment: I tried to bind the state, but still doesn't work, thank you for your answer!